# How to remove blank page at beginning of \documentclass{article} with \usepackage[affil-it]{authblk}

Tags: formatting

When this is typeset, there is a blank page at the beginning before the title page. Is there a way I can remove that whilst still using the \usepackage[affil-it]{authblk}? If not, how can I insert my institution and email into the title page of an article document class?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{setspace}\onehalfspacing
\usepackage[affil-it]{authblk}

\begin{document}

\title{Experiment 3.2: Dimensional Analysis of a Pump}

\author{Sophie Parsons}
  \thanks{CRSid: \texttt{bb45}}
\affil{university}


\date{Dated: \today}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
insert abstract
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

This problem occurred because I used the following package

```
\usepackage[affil-it]{authblk}
```

However, I need this package so I can insert my institute and email address with an article document class.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The macro `\thanks` is issued before the `\maketitle` and creates its own page.  Perhaps you desire `\thanks` to instead be part of the `\author` field?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{setspace}\onehalfspacing
\usepackage[affil-it]{authblk}

\begin{document}

\title{Experiment 3.2: Dimensional Analysis of a Pump}

\author{Sophie Parsons%
  \thanks{CRSid: \texttt{bb45}}}
\affil{university}


\date{Dated: \today}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
insert abstract
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

[image]